# change column value based on some result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE, BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE, BCJTRANS.BOOKCODE, BCJTRANS.MODE,
    BCJTRANS.ENTRYYEAR, BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO, BCJTRANS.AMOUNT
FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
WHERE BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' AND BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
```

Result

```
COMPANYCODE ACCOUNTCODE BOOKCODE    MODE    ENTRYYEAR   ENTRYNO  AMOUNT
RAM         001809      JOURNL       J        16         25      357553.00
RAM         800100      JOURNL       J        16         25     -357553.00
RAM         700100      JOURNL       J        16         25      133414.29
RAM         001809      JOURNL       J        16         25     -133414.29
```

i got 4 result from above query now if **ACCOUNTCODE** column contains  **001809**
then i want all 4 result of **AMOUNT**  column to be zero

i want result as

```
COMPANYCODE ACCOUNTCODE BOOKCODE    MODE    ENTRYYEAR   ENTRYNO  AMOUNT
RAM         001809      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
RAM         800100      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
RAM         700100      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
RAM         001809      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
```

**one more condition is there** 
 if **ACCOUNTCODE** column **does not** contains  **001809**
then i want all  result of **AMOUNT**  column to be zero except **ACCOUNTCODE** with **800100**
i want result as

```
COMPANYCODE ACCOUNTCODE    BOOKCODE    MODE    ENTRYYEAR   ENTRYNO  AMOUNT
    RAM         001780      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
    RAM         800100      JOURNL       J        16         25   -357553.00
    RAM         700100      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
    RAM         001780      JOURNL       J        16         25      0
```

Comment: Add expected result too! (And it will be much easier for us to assist you.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple solution:

```
SELECT 
  BCJTRANS.AMOUNT*
    MIN(CASE WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '001809' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) over()  AMOUNT
FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS 
WHERE BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' AND BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
```

EDIT:

To solve your new question:

```
SELECT 
  BCJTRANS.AMOUNT*
  CASE WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '800100' THEN 1 ELSE
    MIN(CASE WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '001809' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) over()
  END  AMOUNT
FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS 
WHERE BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' AND BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
```

Comment: i have modifed the result please look at it final result i want

Comment: normally you should ask a new question, I updated my answer

Comment: soory i am new to stack over flow i will do next time

Comment: accountcode does not contain 001809  and contains 800100 then i want only **accountcode 800100 with what value it has rest of the result should be zero **  result i have provided above

Comment: are you trying to understand the logic or saying that this provides the wrong result ?

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/4sz2981dv/) this is the result i m getting but i want result i have mentioned above

Comment: I don't understand. Try to make show a table and check off when to show data and what to show

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression and common table expression:

```
with cte_trans as 
(
    select
        BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE, 
        BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE, 
        BCJTRANS.BOOKCODE, 
        BCJTRANS.MODE,
        BCJTRANS.ENTRYYEAR, 
        BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO, 
        BCJTRANS.AMOUNT
    from B_C_J_TRANS as BCJTRANS
    where 
        BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' 
        and BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' 
        and BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
)
select
    COMPANYCODE, 
    ACCOUNTCODE, 
    BOOKCODE, 
    MODE,
    ENTRYYEAR, 
    ENTRYNO, 
    case 
        when exists (select * from cte_trans where ACCOUNTCODE like '%001809%') 
          then 0 
        else AMOUNT 
    end as AMOUNT
from cte_trans
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is he what he actually wants.

Comment: i think what he wants is all 4 result above to be 0 not just 2 of them that account code is 001809

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke You're spot on.

Comment: no if column contains 001809 all result amount column should be made  zero ie. result1,result2,result3,result4 i have given my result above

Comment: Thanks for clarification, guys. @Sahil, see updated answer

Comment: Is that `top 1` in the EXISTS sub-query needed by SQL Server??? (Either one or more rows exist, or not.)

Comment: @jarlh well, technically it is not needed, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can first check account code column:

```
    if exists(select 1 from
    FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
    WHERE BCJTRANS.accountcode=18019)

    SELECT BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE, BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE, BCJTRANS.BOOKCODE, BCJTRANS.MODE,
        BCJTRANS.ENTRYYEAR, BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO, 0 as 'Amount'
    FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
    WHERE BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' AND BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
return

else

    SELECT BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE, BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE, BCJTRANS.BOOKCODE, BCJTRANS.MODE,
        BCJTRANS.ENTRYYEAR, BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO, BCJTRANS.AMOUNT
    FROM B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
    WHERE BCJTRANS.COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND BCJTRANS.ENTRYNO='25' AND BCJTRANS.MODE='J'
```

This will not have implications of checking and doing computations

Answer (score 0):

```
IF   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B_C_J_TRANS WHERE ACCOUNTCODE = '001809' AND COMPANYCODE='RAM' AND ENTRYNO='15' AND MODE='J') 
SELECT     COMPANYCODE, BOOKCODE, MODE, ENTRYYEAR, ENTRYNO, ACCOUNTCODE, AMOUNT * 0 AS AMOUNT
FROM         B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
WHERE     (COMPANYCODE = 'RAM')  AND (ENTRYNO = '15') AND (MODE = 'J')
ELSE
SELECT     COMPANYCODE, BOOKCODE, MODE, ENTRYYEAR, ENTRYNO, ACCOUNTCODE, 
                      CASE WHEN BCJTRANS.ACCOUNTCODE = '800100' THEN BCJTRANS.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS AMOUNT
FROM         B_C_J_TRANS AS BCJTRANS
WHERE     (COMPANYCODE = 'RAM') AND (ENTRYNO = '15') AND (MODE = 'J')
```

i tried this query and got the final result